# ContentControl is not visible when application starts via UI Automation test, but its visible when application starts by user

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress, ui-automation

We are using the prism and WPF to build application. Recently we started using UI Automation (UIA) to test our app. But some strange behavior occurred when we run UIA test. Here's simplified shell:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock 
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
        Name="loadingProgressText"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Text="Loading, please wait..."/>

    <Border
        Grid.Row="0" 
        x:Name="MainViewArea">
        <Grid>
            ...
        </Grid>
    </Border>

    <!-- Popup -->
    <ContentControl 
        x:Name="PopupContentControl"
        Grid.Row="0" 
        prism:RegionManager.RegionName="PopupRegion"
        Focusable="False">
    </ContentControl>

    <!-- ErrorPopup -->
    <ContentControl 
        x:Name="ErrorContentControl"
        Grid.Row="0" 
        prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ErrorRegion"
        Focusable="False">
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

In our app, we use layers (`Popup` and `ErrorPopup`) to hide **MainViewArea**, to deny access to the controls. To show `Popup`, we use next method:

```
    //In constructor of current ViewModel we store _popupRegion instance to the local variable:
    _popupRegion = _regionManager.Regions["PopupRegion"];
    //---

    private readonly Stack<UserControl> _popups = new Stack<UserControl>();
    public void ShowPopup(UserControl popup)
    {
        _popups.Push(popup);

        _popupRegion.Add(PopupView);
        _popupRegion.Activate(PopupView);
    }

    public UserControl PopupView
    {
        get
        {
            if (_popups.Any())
                return _popups.Peek();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Similar to this, we show `ErrorPopup` over all elements of our application:

```
    // In constructor we store _errorRegion:
    _errorRegion = _regionManager.Regions["ErrorRegion"]
    // --- 

    private UserControl _error_popup;

    public void ShowError(UserControl popup)
    {
        if (_error_popup == null)
        {
            _error_popup = popup;
            _errorRegion.Add(_error_popup);
            _errorRegion.Activate(_error_popup);
        }
    }
```

**Mistics...**

When we run it as users do it (double click on app icon), we can see both custom controls (using `AutomationElement.FindFirst` method, or through [Visual UI Automation Verify](http://uiautomationverify.codeplex.com/)). But when we start it using UI Automation test - `ErrorPopup` disapears from the tree of the controls. We trying to start the application like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathToExeFile);
```

I think that we missed something. But what?

**Edit #1**

As @chrismead said, we tried to run our app with `UseShellExecute` flag set to true, but this does not help. But if we start app from **cmd** line, and manually click the button, `Popup` and `ErrorPopup` are visible in automation controls tree.

```
    Thread appThread = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            _userAppProcess = new Process();
            _userAppProcess.StartInfo.FileName = pathToExeFile;
            _userAppProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            _userAppProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            _userAppProcess.Start();

        });
        appThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        appThread.Start();
```

One of our suggestion is when we use method `FindAll` or `FindFirst` to search the button to click, window somehow cached its UI Automation state, and does not update it.

**Edit #2**
We have find, that extension method of prism library `IRegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.OurRegion, typeof(Views.OurView))` have some strange behavior. If we stopped use it, this solve our problem particulary. Now we able to see ErrorView and any kind of view in `PopupContentControl`, and application updates UIA elements tree structure. But this is not an answer - "Just stop use this feature"!

In `MainViewArea` we have a `ContentControl`, which updates it content depending on user actions, and we are able to see only the first loaded `UserControl` to that `ContentControl.Content` property. This is performed like this:

```
IRegionManager regionManager = Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainContentRegion, this.Uri);
```

And if we change the view, no updates will performed in UI Automation tree - the first loaded view will be in it instead. But visually we observe another `View`, and [WPFInspector](http://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/releases/view/64045) shows it properly (its show not a UI Automation tree), but Inspect.exe - not.

Also our suggestion that window use some kind of caching is wrong - caching in UI Automation client we have to turn on explicitly, but we don't do it.

Comment: So, is it correct to say that a simple double click launch of the app results in the control being in the tree, but a Process.Start launch does not?

Comment: Yes, its correct. But we tried 3 way to start app from the code - no one is get us to the right solution...

Comment: Have you tried launching the app from a cmd window?  If that works then using the ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute flag might work.

Comment: We have tried your suggestion. This does not help.

Comment: Might not be related, but in Silverlight (so not quite WPF) our `ContentControl` isn't initialized/rendered until actually viewed on the screen; specifically, it's `Loaded` event is not fired.  If the browser window was minimized, or behind other windows, it never fires the `Loaded` event.  However, once the user restores the window or reorganizes their content so the Silverlight runtime renders the screen, then the `Loaded` event fires automatically.  So yeah, not sure if this is relevant, or even how to get around this for an automated test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm sorry that I've missed some detail, that was the key to the answer. I think that it was not important thing. Anyway.

We used `NavBar` from **DevExpress** controls library for **WPF**. What turns out, is when `NavBar` is present, dynamically created views are not appears on the UI Automation tree. When remove it from the window, there was an ability to see all dynamically loaded views. What does the `NavBar` - still mistic for me.

Here bright example to see what happened, if NavBar is present or absent on the Window (DevExpress is required).

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window xmlns:dxn="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/navbar"
        x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        >
    <Grid Name="ContentGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--Comment NavBar to see dynamic control in UI Automation tree-->
        <dxn:NavBarControl Name="asdasd">
            <dxn:NavBarControl.Groups>
                <dxn:NavBarGroup Header="asdasdasdasd" />
            </dxn:NavBarControl.Groups>
        </dxn:NavBarControl>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Name="Statictb" Text="static is visible in ui automation tree" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Create controls" Height="25"  Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        Grid.SetRow(tb, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(tb, 1);
        tb.Text = "dynamic is not visible, if NavBar here...";
        ContentGrid.Children.Add(tb);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

According to the [DevExpress answer](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q411045.aspx) on their support site:

> After a peer is created, listening of automation events may cause performance issues. We have decided to clear invocation lists of automation events to resolve it. In your specific situation, you need to disabling clearing. To do it, please set the static DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ClearAutomationEventsHelper.IsEnabled property to False in the Window constructor.

This solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that the `ContentControl`'s automation peer should update its children with [`AutomationPeer.ResetChildrenCache()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.peers.automationpeer.resetchildrencache.aspx) after the view has been changed.

[`AutomationPeer.InvalidatePeer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.peers.automationpeer.invalidatepeer.aspx) should have the same effect (in addition to other side effects) and it is supposed to be called automatically in response to the [LayoutUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.layoutupdated.aspx) event. You might want to check that the LayoutUpdated event is raised when the view changes.

Comment: Thank you sooo much for this - I have been struggling for 24 hours with a kind of similar issue where `AutomationElement`s suddenly disappeared. After reading your answer I checked if the `AutomationPeer` children of a given control were re-created during `LayoutUpdated` (and they were not) - so your suggestion with calls to `ResetChildrenCache()` and `InvalidatePeer()` did the trick. Thanks again. +1.

Answer (score 1):

stukselbax, try to find a sequence of keystrokes (TABs, and an ENTER most likely) to click the button that enables you to see the items.  it is pretty easy to send keystrokes and i can add more in here about that if that works for you.  you can always establish a tab order in your application that makes the most sense for users.

------ Update on 6/20/12 --------

Have you tried double clicking a shortcut to your app on the desktop using PInvoke to see if you can see the controls when it is opened that way?  Here is a link to an example here on stackoverflow:

[Directing mouse events [DllImport("user32.dll")] click, double click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739523/directing-mouse-events-dllimportuser32-dll-click-double-click)

Another idea: some of the controls on the app I am currently automating don't show up in the tree until a mouse click occurs on them.  To accomplish this without using any hardcoded coordinates, I find something in the tree which is just (above/below/etc) the place where I need to click to get the control to appear.  I then get the mouse coordinates for that item and put the mouse at a small offset from there and click.  Then I can find my controls in the tree.  If the app is resized, moved around, etc. this will still work since the small offset is still valid.

Comment: Come to think of it.  You might want to start by using Process.Start with a shortcut instead of the actual exe to see if that helps.