# How to force UI automation tree refresh

Tags: c#, user-interface, ui-automation, inspect.exe

I am currently trying to use `System.Windows.Automation` to automate a chrome instance, but at a certain point `AutomationElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition);` returns always 0 children, but I can see them in inspect.exe. When I hit refresh in inspect.exe the elements show up in my app too.

While looking for a solution, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782100/outdated-ui-automation-tree) SO post, that OP had more or less the same issue.
An answer suggested to use:

```
SystemParametersInfo( SPI_SETSCREENREADER, TRUE, NULL, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
PostMessage( HWND_BROADCAST, WM_WININICHANGE, SPI_SETSCREENREADER, 0);
```

I implemented that as:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(int uiAction, int uiParam, IntPtr pvParam, int fWinIni);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

....

const int SPI_SETSCREENREADER = 0x0047;

IntPtr inptrnull = IntPtr.Zero;
const int SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
const int SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 0x02;


IntPtr HWND_BROADCAST = new IntPtr(0xffff);
const int WM_WININICHANGE = 0x001A;

SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETSCREENREADER, 1, inptrnull, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_WININICHANGE, SPI_SETSCREENREADER, 0);
```

But it has no effect.

What am I missing?
Is there a other/better way to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using an obsolete managed UIA implementation (System.Windows.Automation).
It's a known case when it could return not all of the children, it might be the cause.

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-uiautomationoverview?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

> For Windows 7, the API has been rewritten in the Component Object
> Model (COM). Although the library functions introduced in the earlier
> version of UI Automation are still documented, they should not be used
> in new applications.

You might try to use [UIA COM interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nn-uiautomationclient-iuiautomation) instead (Inspect uses the same approach):

1. Add a reference to COM -> UIAutomationClient to your project. This will generate a wrapper for you, so the COM interface will be accessible in the code in a usual OO-style.
2. Create a UI Automation object and do your stuff with UIA elements:

   ```
   IUIAutomation automation = new CUIAutomation();
   // Start with the root element; you could also get an element from the point or current focus
   IUIAutomationElement element = automation.GetRootElement();
   IUIAutomationElementArray foundElements = element.FindAll(TreeScope.TreeScope_Children, automation.CreateTrueCondition());
   for (int i = 0; i < foundElements.Length; i++)
   {
       IUIAutomationElement currentElement = foundElements.GetElement(i);
       // do your stuff with the element: get its properties, etc
   }
   ```
3. If the above doesn't help, you might try to use RawTreeWalker instead of calling FindAll() to traverse the UI tree:

   ```
   IUIAutomationTreeWalker walker = automation.RawViewWalker;
   IUIAutomationElement child = walker.GetFirstChildElement(element);
   var sibling = walker.GetNextSiblingElement(child);
   while (sibling != null)
   {
       // do your stuff with sibling elements (get their child elements, etc)
       sibling = walker.GetNextSiblingElement(child);
   }
   ```
4. I've automated Chrome prevously using UIA and as far as I remember it might respond to UIA calls a bit odd: e.g. sometimes it returns a container element instead of the actual one (button, edit, etc). I resolved this case by doing several attempts until I finally retrieved what expected. What if you call FindAll() several times too?